# neural network in Keras with two different input types - images and values

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

At the moment i have a working CNN that outputs a value from -1 to 1 from a given image. Now I also want to input given values to the network, because they could really add accuracy to the output. That job of course can't be done with a CNN, but it should be possible to add them to the fully connected layers, shouldn't it?
Would be great if somebody showed me how to approach that with Keras.

My current CNN:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x/127.5-1.0, input_shape=(66,200,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(24, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(36, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(48, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='elu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.summary()
```

How I think it should work:
[image]
~Modified graphic from 
https://blog.insightdatascience.com/classifying-e-commerce-products-based-on-images-and-text-14b3f98f899e.

Comment: what's your question here specifically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diego gave the answer I'll just build a model as an example using the [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). Let's assume you have 3 features that you want to 
add to each image. Each feature is a single real number so if we concatenate them we have a feature vector with three components.

```
from keras.layers import ( Conv2D, Flatten, Lambda, Dense, concatenate,
                         Dropout, Input )
from keras.models import Model

image = np.random.rand(10, 66, 200, 3)
feature = np.random.rand(10, 3) # feature vector
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, (10, 1))


image_input = Input(shape=(66, 200, 3))
aux_input = Input(shape=(3,))

lamb = Lambda(lambda x: x/127.5-1.0, input_shape=(66,200,3))(image_input)
cov1 = Conv2D(24, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2))(lamb)
cov2 = Conv2D(36, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2))(cov1)
cov3 = Conv2D(48, 5, 5, activation='elu', subsample=(2, 2))(cov2)
cov4 = Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='elu')(cov3)
cov5 = Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='elu')(cov4)
dropout = Dropout(0.5)(cov5)
flatten = Flatten()(dropout)

# Here we add in the feature vectors 
merge = concatenate([flatten, aux_input])

d1 = Dense(100, activation='elu')(merge)
d2 = Dense(50, activation='elu')(d1)
d3 = Dense(10, activation='elu')(d2)
out = Dense(1)(d3)

model = Model(inputs=[image_input, aux_input], outputs=[out])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit([image, feature], y)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reproduce the model on your image, you can't use `Sequential` from Keras.

You'll need to use `Model`, it will be very similar but with some mods:

- Add the text vector as an extra placeholder/input
- Merge the output of the CNN with the output of the FC layers of the vectorized text
- Finally, add some other FC layers and the output